# Scala - Running main class from library

Tags: scala, sbt

I have 2 sbt projects A is depends on B.
Is there a way to run project A with main class, defined in project B?
Command "sbt run" give me the error, that no main class found in project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to specify your main class (in this case a class of project B) in your build.sbt of project A:

```
mainClass := Some("full.path.in.projectb.Main")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your current project to `B` and run the main class from there.

In SBT shell:

```
project B
run
```

If you are running SBT from command line noninteractively, then:

```
sbt ';project B; run'
```

or:

```
sbt 'project B' run
```

Comment: Or more simply, `B/run`.

Comment: How to find projectId of B?